# Time Difference

Tags: php, postgresql, date, timestamp

I am new to PostgresQL and PHP and am working with a PostgresQL Timestamp object and am trying to find the difference between now and that timestamp to display in terms of years, months, and days. Is there to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: check this so link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964544/timestamp-difference-in-hours-for-postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just subtract two timestamps, the result is an [`interval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html).
To get "now" you can use `now()` or `current_timestamp` (among others).

```
SELECT now() - '2010-02-21 20:11:32';
```

This will display something like this, though:

```
830 days 23:00:50.127241
```

To get a justified representation, use [`age()` or `justify_interval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE)

```
SELECT justify_interval(now() - '2010-02-21 20:11:32');
```

Displays the same value in a format like you seem to be after:

```
2 years 3 mons 20 days 23:01:34.095813
```

If you want a particular output format use [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: great. I tried doing SELECT now() - '2010-02-21 20:11:32'; but I get a syntax error: unexpected T_STRING. Any ideas? Sorry I'm so new to this!

Comment: @MarsJ: Works for me (PostgreSQL 9.1), and I am positive it works with any other version of PostgreSQL this side of the millennium. "error: unexpected T_STRING" is not a PostgreSQL error message. Looks like PHP. A problem with un-escaped single quotes maybe?

Comment: @MarsJ: You might have to cast your string as a timestamp:  `SELECT NOW() - '2010-02-21 20:11:32'::TIMESTAMP;`

Comment: @MarsJ: This works without casting (while casting never hurts to avoid ambiguities). It's a PHP syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
select age(now(), '2010-01-02 12:34:35');
```

The complete version:

```
select substring(a from 1 for (position('days' in a) + 3)) 
from (select (age(now(), '2010-01-02 12:34:35'))::text) s(a)
;
       substring        
------------------------
 2 years 4 mons 30 days
(1 row)
```