# Calculate DATEDIFF in POSTGRES using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I need to calculate **[DATEDIFF](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff)** in minutes between 2 columns of **timestamp** type.
There are so many simple examples on the web, but none of them work really much properly using psycopg2 + sqlalchemy.
I've tried:

```
from sqlalchemy import as sa
from datetime import datetime

# con is a standard pool of connections :class:Connection
con.execute(
    sa.func.datediff(
        sa.literal_column('minute'),
        datetime.utcnow(),
        datetime.utcnow(),
    )
)
```

it throws:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "minute" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT datediff(minute, '2017-02-27T15:04:33.217559'::timest...
                    ^
[SQL: 'SELECT datediff(minute, %(datediff_2)s, %(datediff_3)s) AS datediff_1'] [parameters: {'datediff_3': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 27, 15, 4, 33, 217596), 'datediff_2': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 27, 15, 4, 33, 217559)}]
```

if I try:

```
con.execute(
    sa.func.datediff(
        'minute',
        datetime.utcnow(),
        datetime.utcnow(),
    )
)
```

I receive:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) function datediff(unknown, timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT datediff('minute', '2017-02-27T12:27:49.369724'::time...
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
[SQL: 'SELECT datediff(%(datediff_2)s, %(datediff_3)s, %(datediff_4)s) AS datediff_1'] [parameters: {'datediff_4': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 27, 12, 27, 49, 369740), 'datediff_2': 'minute', 'datediff_3': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 27, 12, 27, 49, 369724)}]
```

Any ideas how to make it right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[PostgreSQL does not have a `datediff` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html). To get the number of minutes, [use the SQL expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964544/timestamp-difference-in-hours-for-postgresql):

```
trunc((extract(epoch FROM newer_date) - extract(epoch FROM older_date)) / 60)
```

- [`extract(epoch FROM …)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=func#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.extract) converts the timestamp to number of seconds.
- `/ 60` converts to seconds to minutes
- `trunc(…)` removes the fractional part.

So probably try

```
sa.func.trunc((
    sa.extract('epoch', datetime.utcnow()) -
    sa.extract('epoch', datetime.utcnow())
) / 60)
```