# SQLAlchemy: Difference between two dates

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'd like to get the difference between two dates working on SQLAlchemy. Using Postgresql I have the following working:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2019-02-11 17:59:05.953894'::timestamp - '2019-02-11 17:59:01.953894'::timestamp))
```

However, I have problems when attempting the same in SQLAlchemy:

```
session.query(func.extract('epoch',func.date(subquery.c.dt_final.cast(Date)))-
                                   func.date(subquery.c.dt_start.cast(Date))).all()
```

Getting this error:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: double precision - date
LINE 1: ...h FROM date(CAST(anon_2.dt_final AS DATE))) - date(CAS...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How is the proper way to get the difference between two dates in SQLAlchemy?

Thanks

Comment: Notice that in the SQLA version you extract, then subtract. In the raw SQL you have it the other way around.

Comment: Also, since in your SQLA version you cast as date, the result of the subtraction would be the number of days between the 2 dates. Did you mean to cast as timestamps instead?

Answer (score 5):

You can use datediff for date diferences:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(Here_you_put_units, '2019-02-11 17:59:05.953894', '2019-02-11 17:59:01.953894');
```

units you can use:

```
year    yy, yyyy
quarter qq, q
month   mm, m
dayofyear   dy, y
day dd, d
week    wk, ww
hour    hh
minute  mi, n
second  ss, s
millisecond ms
microsecond mcs
nanosecond  ns
```

Save as a var:

```
 SELECT  DATEDIFF(Here_you_put_units, '2019-02-11 17:59:05.953894', '2019-02-11 17:59:01.953894') AS needed_date;
```

SQL_alchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import func, text
from datetime import datetime
date1 = datetime.fromisoformat('2019-02-11 17:59:05.953894')
date2 = datetime.fromisoformat('2019-02-11 17:59:01.953894')
func.datediff(text('Here_you_put_units'), date1, date2)
```

Comment: Thanks dreeeeeedd, I found that this is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485952/calculate-datediff-in-postgres-using-sqlalchemy

Comment: did my best :( here we go again

Answer (score 0):

You may need to switch from timestamps to datetime, but there's a built-in function called timediff() which works similarly to things like count() and max(). I'm not familiar with SQLalchemy but it should be pretty universal.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement can be reproduced with this code:

```py
q1 = sa.select(func.extract('epoch',
                            subquery.c.dt_final.cast(TIMESTAMP) -
                            subquery.c.dt_start.cast(TIMESTAMP)))
```

where `dt_start` and `dt_final` are `String` columns containing the timestamp strings in the question.  The result column is a float `(4.0,)`

However in Postgresql we can subtract the timestamps directly

```
test# SELECT 
    '2019-02-11 17:59:05.953894'::timestamp - '2019-02-11 17:59:01.953894'::timestamp AS result;
  result  
══════════
 @ 4 secs
(1 row)
```

so we can do the same in SQLAlchemy:

```py
q2 = sa.select(subquery.c.dt_final.cast(TIMESTAMP) - subquery.c.dt_start.cast(TIMESTAMP))
```

which returns a `datetime.timedelta`: `(datetime.timedelta(seconds=4),)`

If the goal is to subtract dates rather timestamps, cast the timestamp strings to `Date` and subtract

```
q3 = sa.select(subquery.c.dt_final.cast(Date) - subquery.c.dt_start.cast(Date))
```

which will return an integer column, for example `(10,)`.